# How to install the iball 3.5gh-75 modem in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: networking

how should i can install my iball3.5gh-72 modem in Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,is your modem Ubuntu Compatible.

Yes:

1.go to the upper right corner.

[image]

2. VPN connections -> Configure VPN  -> ADD
3. [image]

No:

1.Create a mobile broadband connection [choose connect automatically] showed above.

2.then Run the following command:

```
     sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605
```

Hope this'll help